# How to make Vifm use Neovim to open files?

Tags: neovim, gvim

I have both GVim and Neovim installed.
When I open a file in Vifm, it is opened in GVim and not in Neovim.

How to make Neovim the default editor for Vifm?

Comment: This question is probably off-topic here since it is about Vifm. I think it should be migrated to SuperUser or Unix & Linux.

Comment: @Quasímodo , How to migrate it?

Comment: Since it got an answer, maybe it is better for it to stay here? Hopefully the moderators will know better.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is off-topic as well; we'll discuss what to do with it. In the meantime, it's possible vifm relies on `EDITOR` or `VISUAL`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `set vicmd=vim` to  `set vicmd=nvim` in your [vifmrc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vifm#Customizing_vifm).

Comment: @Quasímodo from [their docs](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%27vixcmd%27), it looks like the default value of `vixcmd` is the value of `vicmd`, and you would only set it if you want something *else* to run in an X session. Is that incorrect?

Comment: True! I missed that, sorry. (Although it might be worth the mention.)